# How to find column name with maximum in row

Tags: r

My dataset is the following:

```
Image   Product_lifestyle   Product_people  Product_text    Product_front   Product_top Actual
Image_001   0.4                      0.1         0.15               0.15    0.1         Product_lifestyle
Image_002   0.35                     0.34        0.05               0.21    0.05        Product_people
```

But I would like to add another column in this dataset. The column name is `predicted`. The values are like `actual`, which is given, but `predicted` is the maximum of the value from column 2:5.
Like predicted of row 1 is `Product_lifestyle`
and predicted of row 2 is `Product_people`

Kindly help me to do it in R

Comment: What are you interested in? The column names or the values?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question the following code should do it.

```
df$predicted <- names(df)[(apply(df[2:6], 1, which.max) + 1)]
```

However given your example data Product_lifestyle would be the predicted column in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(predicted = max(c_across(Product_lifestyle:Product_top)))

  Image     Product_lifestyle Product_people Product_text Product_front Product_top Actual            predicted
  <chr>                 <dbl>          <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>                 <dbl>
1 Image_001              0.4            0.1          0.15          0.15        0.1  Product_lifestyle      0.4 
2 Image_002              0.35           0.34         0.05          0.21        0.05 Product_peopl          0.35
```

If it is the column name you are interested in, you could do the following (with base R):

```
df$predicted <- names(df[2:5])[max.col(df[,2:5])]

      Image Product_lifestyle Product_people Product_text Product_front Product_top            Actual         predicted
1 Image_001              0.40           0.10         0.15          0.15        0.10 Product_lifestyle Product_lifestyle
2 Image_002              0.35           0.34         0.05          0.21        0.05     Product_peopl Product_lifestyle
```